# How do I insert a welcome screen to my Navigation-Based Iphone App?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, uinavigationcontroller

I am new to Iphone App develoment and I was wondering how to insert a welcome screen when my app first start up.  The app is primarily navigation based.  There are tables that users can drill down and see a characteristic of the item that they selected.  I want there to be a welcome screen that gives two options.  But I don't want this to look like a table.  I would prefer a background image and two rounded rect buttons that link to my tables.  Is this possible?  If so, how?

Answer (score 3):

You should add a `Default.png`. This gets shown as your app is loading. Just add it to your project and you have a splash screen. Easy-peasy.

Read the HIG ([Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/Introduction/Introduction.html)) for more info. (Reading the HIG will also smooth over the review process, you're less likely to offend Apple if you follow their rules.)

Comment: I don't think he means a Default.png image. I think he means an initial view that the user sees when the app first starts.

Comment: You could still use a Default.png, and then once you get to applicationDidFinishLaunching, use the same Default.png in a UIImageView with two buttons added.  That way you have a more seamless transition.

Answer (score 3):

First you should define a new `ViewController` backed by a XIB (let's call it `WelcomeController`). Layout the UI however you want (add two Round Rect buttons). Set the background color as @Grumdrig suggested or use a large ImageView as background.

Then, wherever it is that you add the `UINavigationController` to your window, instead add an instance of your WelcomeController.

To dismiss the WelcomeController, simply remove its view from the superview, and insert the NavigationController.

Answer (score 2):

Briefly, create a UIView with two UIButton's within it...

Set the background image with

```
view.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]];
```

I'd suggest you spend some time reading/watching tutorials on http://developer.apple.com/iphone to get some basics concepts.